# round a version in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need to round off a version column , Round() works well with decimal, But doesn't works on something like 7.3.1

```
dbtype        version
------------------------
PostgreSQL     7.3.1
Oracle         11.2.0.4.0
Oracle         12.4.5
```

My desired output

```
PostgreSQL 7
Oracle     11
Oracle     12
```

Comment: Are you really using outdated Postgres versions like 7.1 and 9.1?

Comment: No I am using PostgreSQL 9.5rc1

Comment: Can we remove everything after the first occurrence of decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert it to an array:

```
Select dbtype, (string_to_array(version, '.'))[1]
from the_table
```

Or use split_part:

```
Select dbtype, split_part(version, '.', 1)
from the_table
```

Comment: @KakaDBA: the delimiter must of course be a `.` not a comma. I corrected that